# In Python, given a line number, how do I know which scope it belongs to?

Tags: python

Say I have a simple program:

```
1  def foo():
2     pass
3
4  def bar():
5     pass
```

**Given line number `1` or `2`, I want to know it belongs to function `foo`**.

Same with `4` or `5` for function `bar`.

What's the easiest way to do it? For simplicity, let's just assume "scope" means function or method.

I'm looking at [libCST](https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata.html#position-metadata) as it provides the code position metadata, but it does not provide a mapping from line number to its scope.

Comment: Can you read the .py file as simple text file and count the lines and seek for foo, and use indentation to know where the functions ends.?

Comment: lines don't have scope. Scope is a property of variables. Is your question whether or not  a line belongs to a function?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think it depends on how you look at it: https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/metadata.html#scope-metadata

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ast` to walk over the file structure, determine the line ranges of each function and then find where your specified `lineno` resides.

```
import ast

def find_definition(linenum):
    functions = {}
    with open('input.py') as file:
        tree = ast.parse(file.read())

        for item in ast.walk(tree):
            if isinstance(item, (ast.FunctionDef, ast.AsyncFunctionDef, ast.ClassDef)):
                start, end = compute_size(item)

                functions[item.name] = (start, end)

    for key, value in functions.items():
        if value[0] <= linenum <= value[1]:
            return key, value

def compute_size(node):
    min_lineno = node.lineno
    max_lineno = node.lineno
    for node in ast.walk(node):
        if hasattr(node, "lineno"):
            min_lineno = min(min_lineno, node.lineno)
            max_lineno = max(max_lineno, node.lineno)
    return (min_lineno, max_lineno + 1)

function, func_range = find_definition(1)

print(function, func_range)

#foo (1, 3)

function, func_range = find_definition(4)

print(function, func_range)

#bar (4, 6)
```

There is a much more indepth read found [here](https://julien.danjou.info/finding-definitions-from-a-source-file-and-a-line-number-in-python/).

Answer (score -1):

The standard library [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module will let you parse the file the same way that (your current version of) Python sees it. That will give you a data structure with line number information (`lineno` and `end_lineno` attributes) for each node in your code, as well as columns if you need them.

Then you can go through the data structure in as much detail as you want, mapping line numbers to the corresponding functions.